# Jquery Map error. Can't find map container

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet

I'm using leaflet.js API. This is my code:

```
$( "article" ).hover(
  function(){
    $("#"+this.id).append('<div class="story_map"></div>');
    var map = L.map('story_map', {scrollWheelZoom:false,dragging:true}).setView([23, 23], 3);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/4bf7e7a4096646134526bbafac6eb4838/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);
  },
  function(){
    $(".story_map").remove()
  }
);
```

Why I am not able to initialise the map?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: You might need to add the `div` to the HTML as an element with `display: hidden` so that Leaflet picks up the id properly. I'm not sure it can pick it up if you add the element to the page after the DOM has loaded. Once the map is initialised, just append it to the element and change the CSS to show it.

Comment: L.Map constructor requires the ID of the DOM element, or the reference to the DOM element. You are passing "story_map" which is the class of the DOM element. You can't use class names to instantiate maps. Give your div an ID called "story_map" and that should work.